# Access level control to parts of a resource?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm on a new project and I'm trying to figure out the level of security we're going to be using. At first we thought of a basic read, write permissions scenario. Then it came up that we'll probably will have to restrict the read access to parts of the resources (kind of what Facebook does with the permissions - email, user_about_me, user_birthday, etc...).

We thought about something like: user_basic, user_contact

So if you only have user_basic you will get something like: { id: 1, name: "Tom", lastName: "Doe" }

If you have both you'll get: { id: 1, name: "Tom", lastName: "Doe", phone: "123-123-1234", address: "123 fake street" }

Do you guys know of any packages that help me achieve this more efficiently?

Comment: If my answer works for you, please vote it as best answer so that I may get more reputation and help others out.

Thank you and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're doing (e.g. HTML view or REST application) you could do this multiple ways in symfony.

If HTML, you can just use roles and switches in twig (this is an ugly approach)

```
{% if is_granted("ROLE_WITH_EXTRA_FIELDS") %}
{% endif %}
```

For a rest application, you can use a better approach. JMS Serializer (http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) offers a bundle (http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) that lets you have exclusion strategies. You can mix those with roles at the controller level, to only expose the data you want to people with appropriate roles.

Example taken from http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#creating-different-views-of-your-objects

```
<?php

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

class BlogPost
{
    /** @Groups({"list", "details"}) */
    private $id;

    /** @Groups({"list", "details"}) */
    private $title;

    /** @Groups({"list"}) */
    private $nbComments;

    /** @Groups({"details"}) */
    private $comments;

    private $createdAt;
}
```

In your controller's action something likle this:

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

$serializer->serialize(new BlogPost(), 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('list')));

//will output $id, $title and $nbComments.

$serializer->serialize(new BlogPost(), 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('Default', 'list')));

//will output $id, $title, $nbComments and $createdAt.
```

you would call with something like `setGroups($user->getRoles())` and as long as the roles match the serializer groups, then it should work as expected.